# Automated aligning audio tracks with timings for dubbing screencasts

Tags: python, audio-recording, audio

We have a some screen casts that need to be dubbed to various languages for which we have textual script for the target language as shown below:

```
Begining Time  Audio Narration

0:0            blah nao lorep iposm...

1:20           xao dok dkjv  dwv....

..
```

We can record each of the above units separately and then align it at the proper beginning times as mentioned in the above script.

**Example:**

**Input:**

Input the N timing values: 0:0,1:20 ...
Then input the N audio recordings

**Output:**

Audio recordings aligned to the above timings. An overflow should be detected by the system individually whereas an underflow is padded by silence.

Are there any platform independent audio apis \ software or a code snippet preferably in python that  allows us to align these audio units based on the times provided?

Answer (score 1):

If the input audio files are uncompressed (i.e., WAV files, etc.), the audio library I like to use is libsndfile.  It appears to have a python wrapper here: https://code.google.com/p/libsndfile-python/.  With that in mind, the rest could be accomplished like such:

Open an output audio stream to write audio data to with libsndfile

For each input audio file, open an input stream with libsndfile

Extract the meta-data information for the given audio file based on your textual description 'script'

Write any silence needed to your master output stream, and then write the data from the input stream to the output stream.  Note current position/time.  Repeat this step for each input audio file, checking that the audio clips target start time is always >= the current position/time noted earlier.  If not then you have an overlap.

Of course, you have to worry about sample rates matching etc., but that should be enough to get started.  Also, I'm not exactly sure if you are trying to write a single output file, or one for each input-file, but this answer should be tweekable enough.  libsndfile will give you all the information you need (such as clip lengths, etc.) assuming it supports the input file format.

Comment: Ah, libsndfile is cross-platform, but the python bindings seem to only support OSX (unless it's works to compile from source...but who wants to try that).  Python seems to have a built-in package for WAVE input/output: http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html.